# Can't get Symfony 2 toolbar to display on website

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to do this from a remote computer so the app_dev.php is:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

After the template renders I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Give us a toolbar now will you?</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Looks like valid html and has a body element but no tool bar is there.

I have only ftp access so renamed the Symfony/app/cache folder to gone.

I have confirmed that app_dev.php executes `Debug::enable();` and `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);` (adding an error there causes an error.

I have confirmed that valid html is produced rendering index.html.twig (not a cached one). I have renamed the cache directory.

Not sure what else to check to have it show the tool bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must enable the profiler in `AppKernel.php`

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = ...

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        ...
    }

    return $bundles;
}
```

And make sure that you have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the AppKernel looks like the one you posted and WebProfilerBundle is in Symfony so is the DistributionBundle and GeneratorBundle in senseo. JavaScript is enabled but as you can see in the generated response it doesn't matter because no toolbar is generated, even if JavaScript was disabled the toolbar would show up in the page source.

Comment: Javascript must be enabled because the toolbar is loaded by javascript. But you are right even if the JavaScript is disabled WebProfilerBundle injects a placeholder before </body> tag and it is not in your HTML. You can see here the conditions when the toolbar is loaded: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/EventListener/WebDebugToolbarListener.php#L79. Check especially if you didn't set something like '_format: xml' in your routing file. The toolbar is loaded only when '_format' is set to 'html' (default value).